# Why openssl_get_publickey return NULL?

Tags: php, ssl, oauth

I am writing the authorization process for a program that's built on top of open social. The library that I am using is Oauth library. The certificate has been tested on other machines where it worked perfectly, though the exact same certificate does not work in my computer.

After I trace the error, the problem comes from this function: (inside oauth.php line:207)

```
$publickeyid = openssl_get_publickey($cert);
```

note : `$cert` is RSA Certificate

This function returns NULL on my computer, while it actually works (return valid value) when tested from the other computer. How can I fix this?

Does this have something to do with my Apache or local machine configuration? My `php.ini` and `httpd.conf` seem to be the same as the other machine also. I have been working on this things for several hours, and can't find any related solution in the Internet as well.

Comment: Explain what your $cert variable is defined as.

Comment: Thanks, I have edited the details of the question

Comment: This function should not return null unless the parameter is null. Try using the print_r function for the cert variable and see what turns up. Even if it may seem obvious that the variable is defined.

Comment: I have tried to use print_r for the cert and the result will still be consistent, the variable that I and the previous test supplied to the function was the same, though outputs are different. So confuse